# Loop through JSON object and generate array based on key name

Tags: javascript

I have the following `json` object:

```
[{"i_value":"1","i_value_2":"1"},
{"i_value":"24","i_value_2":"24"}]
```

Then I have the following loop:

```
let setData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    if ('access key name' === 'i_value') {
        setData.push(response.data[i].i_value)
    }
}
setData = setData.map(Number);
console.log(setData);
```

I only want to populate the new `setData` array when the key name `=== i_value` not `i_value_2`

I tried the following:

```
let setData = [];
let keys = Object.keys(response.data);
for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i] === 'i_value') {
        setData.push(response.data[i].i_value)
    }
}
setData = setData.map(Number);
console.log(setData);
```

But this doesn't work. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` to create a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array in the following way:

```js
var response = {}
response.data = [{"i_value":"1","i_value_2":"1"},
{"i_value":"24","i_value_2":"24"}]

let setData = response.data.map(o => Number(o.i_value));

console.log(setData);
```

Comment: And this actually saves me from doing the loop! Many thanks for this!

Comment: @dexter, you are most welcome. And yes, these are the the beauty of array functions......

Answer (score 5):

Just take the original data and `.map`, extracting the `i_value` property:

```js
const input = [{"i_value":"1","i_value_2":"1"},
{"i_value":"24","i_value_2":"24"}];

console.log(
  input.map(({ i_value }) => Number(i_value))
);
```

Also note that there's no such thing as a JSON object. If you have an object, you just have an object; JSON format is a format for *strings* that can be transformed into objects via `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Helpfull! And thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding about JSON object :-).